# Using the contentView property on a custom tableView cell (being passed as a header) how to prevent it from nullifying the custom attributes?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, custom-cell, sections

For example here is my custom cell:

```
protocol SectionHeaderTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didSelectUserHeaderTableViewCell(sectionHeader: SectionHeaderTableViewCell, selected: Bool, type: Type)
}

class SectionHeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelContainerView: LabelContainerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!

    var type: Type?

    var delegate: SectionHeaderTableViewCellDelegate?
    var dog: Dog?

    let sections = [Type.Meals, Type.Exercise, Type.Health, Type.Training, Type.Misc]
}

extension SectionHeaderTableViewCell {
    @IBAction func plusButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let type = type {
            delegate?.didSelectUserHeaderTableViewCell(self, selected: plusButton.selected, type: type )
        }
    }
```

In my controller if I add a return of header.contenView I get the desired results of the header staying in place but unfortunately it nullifies the button included in the custom header preventing it from being called. Otherwise if I simply just return header the button on the custom header cell works as expected but the header moves with the row being deleted which is obviously unsightly and not what I want.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sectionHeader") as? SectionHeaderTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    header.delegate = self
    header.updateDogWithGender(dog)

    header.type = header.sections[section]

    header.sectionTitleLabel.text = header.sections[section].rawValue

    return header.contentView
}
```

[moving headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3wKO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into a similar situation the solution was to create a Nib file and customize it as you see fit. Create a nib file by going to File -> New File -> iOS -> User Interface -> and selecting View. [Create Nib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX5px.png). I added my views and buttons to get the look I wanted. [customize Nib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7hMw.png). From there I changed the custom cell class to be UITableViewHeaderFooterView instead and reconnected my outlets and actions to the new Nib file.

```
class SectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {... previous code from above }
```

Back in the controller update the viewForHeaderInSection function to load a nib instead :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SectionHeader", owner: self, options: nil).first as? SectionHeaderView

    header?.delegate = self
    header?.updateDogWithGender(dog)

    header?.type = header?.sections[section]

    header?.sectionTitleLabel.text = header?.sections[section].rawValue

    return header
}
```

By the way we declared the property first at the end of the loadNibNamed property because it returns an array of AnyObjects and since my Nib file only contains one UIView that houses a label and a button I only needed the first and only item in the array. Thanks to my mentor James for figuring this out!